# Перенос с ms sql в mysql с кириллицей и заменой символа python

Tags: python, mysql, sql-server

Переношу с одной таблицы(ms sql   Cyrillic_General_CI_AS ) в другую (mysql  utf_general_ci) как можно нормально их конвертировать чтобы отображались так как надо?

И еще вопрос как убрать впереди символ _ который есть в таблице ms sql, при переносе мне надо его убрать пример (_Ц-000663192) а надо (Ц-000663192)

```
cur_my = conn_my.cursor()
cur_ms = conn_ms.cursor()
cur_ms.execute("SELECT item_id, id_group FROM items")
for row in cur_ms.fetchall():
    cur_my.execute(
    "INSERT INTO items_in_dbo (item_id,  id_group) VALUES (%s, %s)",
    (row[0], row[1])
)
conn_my.commit()
```

Comment: *как можно нормально их конвертировать чтобы отображались так как надо?* Перенос через клиентскую программу - это плюс дополнительные конвертации. Куда как разумнее выгрузить в текстовый файл и импортировать из него. *как убрать впереди символ _ который есть в таблице ms sql, при переносе мне надо его убрать пример (_Ц-000663192) а надо (Ц-000663192)* После импорта выполнить `UPDATE table SET column = TRIM(LEADING '_' FROM column)`.

Comment: @Akina спасибо за TRIM но мне именно надо реализовать это через python, нету чтоли совсем других выходов?

Comment: *нету чтоли совсем других выходов?* Да есть, как не быть (не спрашивай меня как именно - не моя область).,. просто описанный способ наиболее контролируемый и с минимальным количеством промежуточных геморроев (если не считать копирования данных средствами MS SQL через linked server - но там свои заморочки, и не факт что они проще).

Answer (score 0):

```
import pymssql
import pymysql

**CHARSET = "cp1251"**
conn_ms = pymssql.connect(server=SERVER, user=USER, password=PASSWORD, database=DATABASE, **charset=CHARSET)**


conn_my = pymysql.connect(               
                             cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
 
cur_my = conn_my.cursor()
cur_ms = conn_ms.cursor()
cur_ms.execute("SELECT item_id, id_group FROM items")
for row in cur_ms.fetchall():
    cur_my.execute(
    "INSERT INTO items_in_dbo (item_id,  id_group) VALUES (%s, %s)",
    (row[0], row[1])
)
conn_my.commit()
**cur_my.execute("UPDATE items_in_dbo SET item_id = TRIM(LEADING '_' FROM item_id)")**
conn_my.commit()

conn_ms.close()
conn_my.close()
```

Comment: Стили текста в коде не работают, делайте акцент на нужные места комментариями кода